# Fire and Forget using Async over Sync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, umbraco

We are using Umbraco 8 which have IComponent which allows us to hook events(which does not have async support). We have enabled hook like,

```
public class MyHookComponent : IComponent
{
    private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    static MyHookComponent()
    {
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new SomeBaseUrl;
    }

    public MyHookComponent(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        ContentService.Published += OnNodePublished;
    }

    private void OnNodePublished(IContentService contentService, ContentPublishedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do some work
        Task.Run(() => SomeAsyncWork(url));
    }

    private async Task SomeAsyncWork(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(typeof(MyHookComponent), ex);
        }
    }
```

Fire and forget style is from https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#async-void

Does the above code lead to deadlock or thread starvation as I we got some issue(very slow response after this change suddenly) on staging which (but no dump for investigation).

We have System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.7.0

Comment: Not a real answer to your question, but I would advise you to use `ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)` after `PostAsync`. This will improve performance since the await callback doesn't have to synchronize with the synchronization context. It will also prevent deadlocks. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/

Comment: *"we got some issues"* - What are those issues?

Comment: @L01NL That won't do anything since `Task.Run` is being used, so `SomeAsyncWork` is being run outside the synchronization context of the request anyway. It's really not a great idea to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere anyway, for reasons I wrote about [here](https://www.gabescode.com/dotnet/2022/02/04/dont-use-configureawait.html).

Comment: @GabrielLuci I mean very slow response after this change suddenly. Do you think the above code (that is doing HTTP POST request on background) cause any issue or it should not be related?

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)